# sass : import only a part

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have 2 scss files, I want to use one mixin from the first into the second, but without importing the rest of the file ( I have a few url() who don't react well into this file

someDir/F1.scss

```
@mixin somemixin($width, $height) {
}

.someClass {
  @include somemixin(17px, 10px);
  background-image: url('./someUrl');
 }
```

anotherDir/anotherAnotherDir/F2.scss

```
  @import '../../someDir/F1';
 .someOtherClass {
   @include somemixin(17px, 10px);
   background-image: url('./someOtherUrl');
 }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead try @use module instead of @import and make only mixins public or decide on what you want to make public from file 1.

Check it here

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use